# Why Conan shows me "ERROR: Specify the 'user' and the 'channel' or neither of them" when I try to run "conan export-pkg . hello/0.1@myuser/testing"?

Tags: conan

I'm trying to use

`conan export-pkg . hello/0.1@myuser/testing`

command following the tutorial from https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/existing_binaries.html. But `conan` keeps showing this error message:

`ERROR: Specify the 'user' and the 'channel' or neither of them`.

It doesn't make any difference if I remove both `user` and `channel`.

I tried:

- `conan export-pkg . hello/0.1`
- `conan export-pkg . hello`
- `conan export-pkg .`

And I got the same error every time. What is this error message about and how can be resolved? What am I doing wrong?

My `conan` version is: 1.29.0

Comment: That tutorial works, please, update your Conan client to the latest version and try again. You are running 1.29.0 which is +1 year old, the current version is 1.45.0. To update your client, follow the documentation: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html#update

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need this version for some reasons, Don't you think that even with an older version the error message is expected?

Comment: It seems to be broken. I don't think it has anything to do with the version of the conan even the error is incorrect when you have specified both user and channel. BTW I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to work around this problem after submitting an [issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/10913) to the Conan developers.

I had changed the `storage.path` setting in my `conan.conf` to a top-level folder of drive `D:\`:

```
# File: <username>/.conan/conan.conf

# ...

[storage]
# (default) Relative path to a folder in C:\
#path = ./data

# Absolute path to a top-level folder in D:\
path = D:\conan_packages
```

After a while, it just stopped working.

I worked around this by setting `storage.path` to a non top-level folder of `D:\`, e.g.

```
[storage]
path = D:\conan\packages
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I was dealing with this weird issue for a long time! Your solution solved my problem. Do you know the exact reason of the issue? I'm asking just to learn.

Comment: Since I was able to find this workaround, the Conan team decided it was not worth investigating further. I believe you may re-open my [issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/10913) if you need a full solution.